# Azure Virtual Machine is stuck in Running (Provisioning) mode

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

We created an image from a virtual machine that was running perfectly fine on azure(from last 1 year). This machine has lots of configuration. We executed sysprep utility and created image. We followed all steps mentioned in below article.

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/how-to-guides/capture-an-image/

Now we are trying to create VM using that image and received provisioning timeout issue 2 times. No further information is received along with time out issue. We started one more time, but still it’s showing in provisioning mode.

vhd of actual machine is still available in storage.  We tried to create machine from the disk option. In this case machine created successfully and status shown as running, but RDP didn't worked. Following information was also missing on that machine:

1)     Host Name

2)     RDP CERTIFICATE THUMBPRINT

We need assistance to get back the original machine. Please suggest as it’s critical to production.

Comment: Have you tried the forum of azure on microsofts msdn? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/e4387e57-02f8-4cfb-8f17-2ef4c9cc492d/meaning-of-status-running-provisioning-timed-out

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  It's because I accidentally skipped the second part of step 4 of [this article](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-capture-image-windows-server/)

> In System Cleanup Action, select Enter System Out-of-Box Experience (OOBE) and make sure that Generalize is checked. For more information about using Sysprep, see How to Use Sysprep: An Introduction.